# File uninitalized when using Python in C#

Tags: c#, python, file, variables, encoding

I fighting with this problem. I try to Open a file and save it to a variable.
Then I want to encode it with the Poster library which I included.

So that's the part of the code that doesn't work... (you don't have to worry about the rest)

```
try:
    poster.streaminghttp.register_openers()
    #Open File to be Uploaded
    file = open("D:\\HC1100\config.cfg", "rb")
    print "uplaod process"

    #Encode Parameters for the Device
    params = [('restore', file), ('upload', 'PC ==> Unit')]
    datagen, headers = poster.encode.multipart_encode(params, 'ff2fbffcc75148fb9b7ba9885a1cf146')
    file.close()
```

So I get the following error message: 
"Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Uninitalized' to type 'System.Exception'"

The funny thing is, if I write a .txt with the same code... and I execute it with the
IronPython.exe it works! but it doesn't work if I do it in a C# Python Project.

Thanks for help and Happy 2013!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the IronPython Compiler included in Visual Studio is not able to handle this kind of file-Handling in combination with the poster library.

But it is possible to call the Python File with a C# Project, and not a C#-Python Project.